# Laravel: Cannot add foreign keys constraints on production

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I’m developing a Laravel project and I created the models, when I run the migrations on my computer (where I’m developing) everything works fine, even the relations between tables. The problem comes when I upload the code to the production server and when I run the migrations where I create the relations, I got an error.

In the code below I leave some commented lines, those lines are things that I tried to do to solve the problem, but nothing worked.

- I tried to set the table engine to innoDB on both tables, but it didn’t work.
- I tried to set the `id` datatype as `increments` on both tables, and the column `deviceTypeID` that is going to serve as foreign key, I defined it as `unsigned` and `integer` and it didn’t work.
- I even checked the PHP, Composer, Doctrine/dbal and mysql versions on both computers and are the same (or almosr the same).

Developing Computer:
PHP: 7.3
Composer: 1.8.6
MySQL Server: 5.7.23
Doctrine/dbal: 2.9

Production Server:
PHP: 7.3
Composer: 1.9
MySQL Server: 5.7.25
Doctrine/dbal: 2.9
(It runs Ubuntu Server 18.04)

- I also tried to run the project on another computer an see if I got the same error, but it didn't come, everything worked fine.
- I also ran this query "alter table `devices` add constraint `devices_devicetypeid_foreign` foreign key (`deviceTypeID`) references `devicestype`(`id`) on delete cascade" without all the quotes directly on mysql command line and it worked. So the problem is not related to the user privileges.

It always crash on production when it tries to run the code on  `AddRelationDevicesDeviceType`

```
class CreateDevicesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('devices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //$table->engine = 'innoDB'
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            //$table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('deviceTypeID');
            //$table->integer('deviceTypeID')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}

class CreateDevicesTypeTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('devicesType', function (Blueprint $table) {
           //$table->engine = 'innoDB'
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            //$table->increments('id');
            $table->string("Device Type");
            $table->text("Description");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}


class AddRelationDevicesDeviceType extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('devices', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('deviceTypeID')
                            ->references('id')->on('devicesType')
                            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `devices` add constraint `devices_devicetypeid_foreign` foreign key (`deviceTypeID`) references `devicestype`(`id`) on delete cascade) at /var/www/html/MYPROJECT/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the databa se's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint") /var/www/html/MYPROJECT/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:119

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint") /var/www/html/MYPROJECT/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:117
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you format your question a little better?  Newlines are helpful to help people read, and code should be in `codeblocks`.  See our [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) guide!  You seem to be missing spaces before your dashes -- that'll make them bullet points.

Comment: Both columns type need to match. Did you tried used `bigInteger`/`bigIncrements` on both?

Comment: You can run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` command in your database and see the exact error, then show us.

Comment: Are you sure that the foreign key constraint or others on the same field are not already defined in production?

Comment: There's most likely a different between your development and production database. You can figure out by copying over the production database to your development environment and execute the same migration there. I bet you'll get the same error there.

Comment: @Cullub I'm really sorry this is my very first post and I had so much rush to don't miss anything while I was writting.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I tried changing the columns type to bigInteger on the “devices” table and let the id as bigIncrements on the devicesType table, but it didn’t work.     When I ran the commando you told me I got this message:                      2019-08-09 06:12:43    0x7fb7e40b4700 Error in foreign key constraint of table redmi@002du/#sql-cff_1d: foreign key (`deviceTypeID`) references`devicestype` (`id`) on delete cascade: Cannot resolve table name close to: (`id`) on delete cascade

Comment: @dparoli Yes I'm pretty sure, I even connected using the MySQL Workbench and I used the tool to create the EER Diagram and see the changes, but there is no any relations between tables.

Comment: Ok now you have the error  `Cannot resolve table name`.. double check table names. MySQL can be case sensitive, depending on the configuration.

Comment: @Candy no problem!  You can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57420112/edit) your post to add new info, or to tweak the stuff you have there already.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, specially to PtrTon, you were right my production database were different from my development database, and @FelippeDuarte the command SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; was really helpful and your supposition about the case sensitive were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I I figured out how to solve my problem.

The problem was when I ran the first migration where I create the table “devicesType” MySQL changed the table name to lower case, so it ended up being “devicestype” and when I tried to refer that table in the last migration where I create the relation Laravel couldn’t find the table.

My development server wasn’t case sensitive while my production server was case sensituve.

I also change the "deviceTypeID" from "unsignedBigInteger" to "bigInteger" and I specify the the type unsigned using the method "unsigned"

This is my new code if is useful to someone:

```
class CreateDevicesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('devices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('deviceTypeID')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}

class CreateDevicesTypeTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('devicestype', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string("Device Type");
            $table->text("Description");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}


class AddRelationDevicesDeviceType extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('devices', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('deviceTypeID')
                            ->references('id')->on('devicestype')
                            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
}
```